# How to get interest in the mathematics of tax

Tags: soft-question, finance, education

In a similar vein to my previous thread, I will also be teaching about the mathematics behind taxation - to a lot of people, this is very mundane - but that is not true of everyone. The practicality of this mathematical topic is undeniable, so it is easy to make relevant (as tax is one of the certainties in life).

My question is, what are some strategies to make teaching of the mathematics of tax interesting? or even, fun?

Comment: Teach it from the perspective of the government, then it's almost fun all the different ways you're getting income.

Comment: @vadim123 I love it!! Some of the budding world leaders in the class will too!

Comment: What falls under the label "mathematics of tax"? Perhaps there are other interesting phenomena that can be described by the same mathematics.

Comment: @Brad the topics include mainly percentages and quite a bit of problem solving, as the level of tax is linked to the income level here. However, I find it is best to stay in context as too many contexts can confuse the issue.